# What's the purpose of memory alignment and why I do need it?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-alignment, low-level

I've been reading so much about memory alignment and I didn't get it, I know that's an important method that you have to keep in mind to write efficient code. But I got confused.

Comment: Try wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Answer (score 0):

Basically, CPUs read data from memory a "word" at a time, word being the natural bit-ness of the CPU. If a multi-byte value is not aligned on a word boundary, the CPU has to issue two (or more) reads to get the value, and that is less efficient. Same thing with writing.

Comment: That's an oversimplification.  Some processors require larger data types to be more restrictively aligned than on a word boundary.  It's not uncommon for a `double` to be more restrictively aligned than an `int`, where an `int` is regarded as the "word size".

Comment: @TomKarzes: Yes, it is absolutely an oversimplification.